# Font style doesn't change in Inkscape

Tags: fonts, inkscape

I am recreating a logo from an image in Inkscape to have it as a vector graphic. I need to write some text in Microsoft YaHei Light, which I have already installed in Windows. In Microsoft Word I can write in Microsoft YaHei normal or bold, and then I have another font called Microsoft YaHei Light which also has options for normal or bold. However in Inkscape, I only have one Microsoft YaHei font and a styles table with two columns which are CSS and Face, and the following three rows: weight=290 and Light, Normal and Regular, Bold and Bold. Bold is visibly different from Normal, but "weight=290" does not change anything. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: As a fix in case it is of use to anyone: if I write the text in Microsoft YaHei Light in Word and the copy and paste it into Inkscape, it gets pasted as a text object correctly and with the correct font. Now in the fonts list I have an entry for Microsoft YaHei Light, but it is crossed out in red and with a warning icon that reads the tooltip: "Font not found on system"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Work around

1. You could add your needed text in Word
2. Export/Save the document in PDF format
3. Open/Import the PDF into Inkscape
4. Continue turning the logo into a vector

This will hopefully give you the result you are after